# Formato condicional DataGridView ASPX

Tags: asp.net

A ver si alguien resolvió algo como esto...
En una columna de un gridview quiero mostrar dos formatos, Así como en la imagen:

[image: A esto quiero llegar]

Actualmente estoy utilizando:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cantidad" DataField="cantidad" ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataFormatString="{0:N2}>
```

Lo anterior me da el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saben si existe alguna propiedad /evento que me ayude.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una propiedad solo para mostrar el dato, y ahí aplicar el condicional.

Ejemplo

```
public MiClase{

  public decimal cantidad { get; set; }

  public string cantidadDisplay
  {
     get
     {
        if(Math.Truncate(cantidad) == cantidad) {
            return cantidad.ToString("N0");     
        }
        return cantidad.ToString("N2");
     }
  }
}
```

Y luego es esta propiedad la que pones en el DataGrid

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cantidad" DataField="cantidadDisplay" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
```